# Extending well known phrase

Tags: idiom, motto

I was thinking about this recently, but my latin knowledge is restricted to well known academic phrases like *in vitro*, *de jure*, *etc.* and others like *ad nauseam* or *in vino veritas*, thus this question.

Would the phrase *memento mori et revixi* be a somewhat valid extension of the well known phrase *memento mori?* Or would it be *memento mori et reviviscere?* Or something else entirely would be the way to go?

I know that to ancient Romans rebirth/reincarnation was not a known/established concept. Still I am thinking about "retconning" something along the lines of modern interprations of reincarnations into the phrase. Is this possible as mentioned above or in some similar, succint fashion?

**Update:** more context and clarification about what I am looking for.

*Memento mori* is a culturally and historically "loaded" term in Europe (and generally in "the West"), often used as motto, etc., but I am regarding it mostly from the medieval philosophic/artistic perspective, which gave birth to dance macabre and related things. *Memento mori* for me is about "remember death" in the meaning of "you are mortal, you will die, live accordingly, as if every breath you take may be your last".

With this question I am looking for an extension of this phrase with the concept of rebirth/reincarnation (but **not** rejuvenation/becoming younger in the same physical body). As in: "remember death, you are mortal, you will die, live accordingly, but at the same time do not forget life *after* death, that death is inevitable but not a definite end". Alternative phrases to rebirth, reincarnation, which come to mind in English now are: restart (starting again), anew, back to the beginning, closing the circle.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What do you want this new phrase to mean? For example, I could well interpret the English "remember to die and live again" two ways: you have to remember both things, or you have to remember and live. In Latin these would look different. Please explain what the desired meaning is and is not. The correct extension depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta thank you for the welcome! I actually was looking for this kind of ambiguity, as it works in English "remember death and life", as in: remember death as an inevitable thing, but embrace life before OR embrace that there is life after death (either in Heaven, Hell, Hél, Hades, whatever your belief is, or as in reincarnation as in living again). If that does make sense. So I'm looking for each if those, in case they are different? But the meaning of "live/rise again" is my main focus.

Comment: Can you edit a more detailed description of your goal into your question? If you want a specific ambiguity, it might be that there simply is none or Latin has to take a very different route to it. Elaboration on the desired meaning or nuance helps a lot, especially with Latin which doesn't have as nice a one-to-one correspondence with English vocabulary as some modern languages do.

Comment: I closed the question for lack of detail. It can certainly be reopened once edited.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I have updated the question as you suggested. In case still not sufficient, I can try and update again, otherwise please consider reopening.

Comment: Thanks! Reopened.